# Unable to find illegal Characters in Path

Tags: c#, string, url, illegal-characters

I am unable to find illegal characters in

> www.rightmove.co.uk/propertyMedia/redirect.html?propertyId=47772832&contentId=778055923&index=0

This is the URL I took from my debugger.

I use the above URL in this method of `WebClient`

```
string document = w.DownloadString(url);
```

This throws an exception:

> Argument Exception :Illegal Characters in path

The URL works fine when I copy it into Chrome directly. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you including the protocol (http or https)?

Comment: What type of exception is being thrown? A `WebException'? If you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find out that you need a proper Web address starting with a protocol such as "http://".

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Argument Exception

Comment: try this please, what happens? `url = "http:// www.rightmove.co.uk/propertyMedia/redirect.html?propertyId=47772832&contentId=778055923&index=0";`.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Same exception :(

Comment: @Charlie: what is the setting of the property `BaseAddress`? An empty string?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Your Url solved the problem but it had space before 'www'. Now it is working fine thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is because the protocol is missing (`http` or `https`)

Use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` to check if an `Uri` is valid.

False:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("www.rightmove.co.uk/propertyMedia/redirect.html?propertyId=47772832&contentId=778055923&index=0",UriKind.Absolute);
```

True:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://www.rightmove.co.uk/propertyMedia/redirect.html?propertyId=47772832&contentId=778055923&index=0",UriKind.Absolute);
```